# post->ID displays the same ID number for every post

Tags: posts, loop

In the front page, I made a grid structure with a custom loop

```
    <?php 
        $query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'category_name'=>'services', 'posts_per_page'=>7, 'orderby'=>'date' ) );
        if($query->have_posts()):
            while($query->have_posts()):$query->the_post();
    ?>

        <div class="my_grid_single my_top_grid page_slider">
            <a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( '400' ); ?>
                <figcaption>
                    <h5><?php echo the_title(); ?></h5>
                    <a class="ion-arrow-right-c" href="<?php get_the_permalink(); ?>"></a>
                </figcaption>
            </a>
        </div>

    <?php endwhile;wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    <?php else: ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Then on the single.php page, I did the following code

```
<?php 


if(have_posts()):
      while(have_posts()):the_post(); ?>

    <?php echo the_title(); ?>
    <?php echo the_content(); ?>
<?php 
    endwhile;
    endif;
 ?>
```

Now, the post; single.php displays the entire posts of the website instead of just the queried one.

I am going mad at this.

Could someone please assist?

Thanks

Comment: `the_title` echo's internally, so that `echo` does nothing. You're also missing an `echo` on `get_the_permalink`. You also shouldn't overwrite `$wp_query` like that, it'll cause problems, so remove the `global` statement, and use a different name, such as `$q = new WP_Query`. You're also missing an if statement to check if any posts were found, and a `wp_reset_postdata` call at the end to cleanup so it doesn't mess up your template after the loop

Comment: Also `single.php` is the template WP uses when a single post is loaded, your front post grid won't be loading `single.php`, you never tell it to

Comment: Thanks, Tom, for your comments. I have made some changes as per your suggestions, such as; I changed the loop to new WP_query (changes are made above). Then in single.php, I used a simple loop. But still, it displays all the posts instead of the specific post. Even when I visit the posts directly from admin dashboard, the page still displays all the posts.

Comment: Do you have a URL where we can see the problem?

Comment: I think we have a fundamental misunderstanding about how templates are loaded here. You're expecting the contents of `single.php` to be inside your loop on the frontpage?

Comment: I think Tom is correct.  The template hierarchy might be of use here:  https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#single-post